# Найти минимальное число

Tags: javascript, функции

Как найти минимальное число в javascript (function) ??

Comment: вероятно, `Math.min`?

Comment: Прими, пожалуйста, ответ нажатием на галочку слева от него.

Answer (score 2):

```js
console.log(Math.min(100, 12, 8, 10, 23, 14))
console.log(Math.min.apply(Math, [100, 12, 8, 10, 23, 14]))
```

Comment: Неужели нет ни одного вопроса-дубликата?

Comment: Ну я не видел. Можно этот сделать, когда галочку поставят)